# Regex expression that locates a null value

Tags: sql, regex

I need a regex that locates a null value.

I'm working with an application that has a bug in its query generator:

I'm not able to design a query to test **value IS NULL**

`select * from table where column is null`

Instead, I have to design a query using **value MATCHES [regex]**

`select * from table where column matches ^`

**Is there a regex that resolves/locates a null value?**

Here's a screenshot of the GUI query editor; the text box accepts regex expressions

Note: The example below doesn't work (ignore the cursor next to the caret)

[image: Query Builder]

Comment: What [tag:rdbms] is this?

Comment: You can't match a null value with a regular expression. `NULL` is very special in SQL, it can only be match with `IS NULL` and `IS NOT NULL`. All other tests of a null value return `NULL`, even `NULL = NULL`

Comment: How about the reverse approach:  value <> [expression that resolves to not null]

Comment: like this...  WHERE value REGEXP .{}

Comment: Use `coalesce` to first turn `NULL` into some agreed string, like `"NULL"`: `WHERE COALESCE(value, 'NULL') REGEXP .....`. Then the parameter should have `^NULL$` to have a match with `NULL`.